# Manage country wise databases on different servers in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store

I have current a developed app which I am going to submit in just few days .

Currently The Application shows  data by calling a web service and fetches data from a server .

Now client requirement is to build two different databases.

So the question is should I make two different builds for two different countries or should I make alternative call to the web services based on the format region selected in the iPhone .

```
e.g, if ( country == uk ) then 
           call uk_Service;
     else if( country == us ) then 
           call us_Service;
```

Please tell me which approach is better. And also if should I make two different builds then can I submit both of them at a time in the AppStore .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the if/else option purely because maintaining 2 apps instead of one will be more work - eg when you want to fix a bug you'll have to do it twice over. Another advantage of using the localised version is that a user can change their localisation and start using the correct database - eg they buy the app in the US and then move to the UK, change their settings and can start using the UK database without a problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a good idea to have two different builds for the App Store. This would mean that you have to do all the organisatorial overhead in iTunes Connect twice. For example an update with all the screen shots and textual descriptions have to be submitted twice. Also you do not have a chance to ensure the release of both submissions will be synchronous.

Why don't you provide a setting to the user where he can choose the country he wants to use your app for?